# Atoms in category theory

Tags: category-theory, terminology

Euclid defines a point as that which has no parts. This translates easily in categorical terms: given a category $C$, an object $A$ is called an atom if $A$ is not initial and if all monomorphisms into $A$ are either isomorphisms or initial morphisms.

Here are a few examples,

- In the category of sets, atoms are the singletons
- In the category of groups, atoms are the finite cyclic groups $(\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{p\mathbb{Z}},+)$, with $p$ prime
- In the category of unital rings, atoms are the $\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{n\mathbb{Z}}$, for all $n\in\mathbb{N}^*$
- In the opposite category of commutative unital rings (aka affine schemes), atoms are fields
- In a poset with a minimum, atoms are elements just above the minimum
- In a poset without a minimum, atom are the minimal elements

Do these atoms exist in the categorical literature under another name? Do they have uses other than the cases above?

Comment: Sounds related to the concept to the concept of [simple objects](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/simple+object).

Comment: In the opposite category of groups, the atoms are simple groups. I think the dual category atoms are, in a lot of cases, more fruitful. We learn quite a bit about commutative rings and groups by studying fields and simple groups.

Comment: For posets with a minimum element, atom is the standard name.